# Can HDMI Transmit Touch Screen Data using MHL Adapter

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, touchscreen, smartphone

I did a bit of research into MHL (Mobile High-Definition Link) and discovered it has the following feature according to Wikipedia:

> HDMI-CEC control of remote devices.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_High-Definition_Link

Additionally, the MHL specification states:

> Fully interoperable remote control features to navigate and control mobile device media playback, apps and other extensive features

http://www.mhlconsortium.org/about/FAQs.aspx

Does this mean that if I connect my smartphone to a touchscreen monitor using an MHL to HDMI adapter - I can control the phone with a secondary touchscreen?

Comment: This style of control is similar to other styles of control used before this.  The base idea for it is so the user controls say the TV , and the tv has features to talk back to the DVD player, or the Cable box, or a media box. A way to bring all your media devices control together.  This type of communications between devices has been done about 3 time in 10 years using different methods. Even with the standard it worked best when you purchaced your whole media system from the same company, or they are marketing it to work with your dvr or something.

Comment: If somehow you could get what your asking for , it is likely to be when you have the Same companies phone as you do thier tv or something. ""Trade names for CEC are Anynet+ (Samsung), Aquos Link (Sharp), BRAVIA Link and BRAVIA Sync (Sony), HDMI-CEC (Hitachi), E-link (AOC), Kuro Link (Pioneer), INlink (Insignia), CE-Link and Regza Link (Toshiba), RIHD (Remote Interactive over HDMI) (Onkyo), RuncoLink (Runco International), SimpLink (LG), T-Link (ITT), HDAVI Control, EZ-Sync, VIERA Link (Panasonic), EasyLink (Philips), and NetCommand for HDMI (Mitsubishi)"".  <---- EX LG makes phones and TVs

Answer (score 1):

No. But not really *no*, more like a technically no.

HDMI-CEC requires both the TV and the receiver understands each other. For example, most remotes are built using a type of arrow navigation component. Since this is understood to be on most remotes and used by most TVs, receivers understand these inputs.

If both the TV and receiver understood the instruction (ex. tap here) it could be used.